# Firefox - Shortcut for activating bookmarks in Bookmarks Toolbar?

Tags: macos, keyboard, firefox

Are there any keyboard shortcuts for activating bookmarks in the Bookmarks Toolbar for Firefox?

(Similar to the +1, +2, ..., keyboard shortcuts for Safari.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not built-in, but it is available through a no-restart extension called [Bookmark Shortcut Keys](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/bookmark-shortcut-keys/):

> Access Bookmark Toolbar items with a keyboard shortcut.
>
> The default is Control+1-9. Change it in the preferences.

Note that you have to organize your bookmarks toolbar with up to nine of your favorite links at the beginning of the list to use it. There is no way to map a specific number to a specific link (except by the order in which they appear).

Note:
In my use, I could not get <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1-9</kbd> to work because it's used to navigate to open tabs. But it did work with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1-9</kbd>.
I didn't use the default <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>1-9</kbd> because that's mapped to switching spaces in OS X and I didn't want to re-map it.